# uninstall ubuntu 14 and reinstall window 8.1

Tags: uninstall

I have tried to uninstall and reload windows but I can't. I have tried everything in other posts and nothing seems to work.  Even tried to just clean partition and then reinstall got the grub rescue screen. Even tried to do that didn't work. I have now reinstalled so can you give me step by step instructions on how to do it please.

UPDATE

I have discovered that Windows 8.1 computers do not come with recovery discs.  They have the software on a virtual drive on the HDD.  When you get the machine you are supposed to do a back up of it on either several DVD's or on a 16GB USB drive.  The product code is part of the Bios of the machine.  So when you install Ubuntu on a Windows 8 machine you need to partition FIRST!  The installer will not do it automatically for you.  Something I have found out to my cost as I now have to pay for a recovery disc from Acer.  :(

Comment: Without *a lot* of details about exactly what you have tried and what happened, I think the best we can do is still to refer you to [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Well I tried to install OS uninstaller and that didn't work.  I then went into try Ubuntu to see if that worked but it didn't. I ended up deteting the partition forgetting that I need Grub to install windows.

Comment: Ok found out why I couldn't...  Windows 8 computers do not come with recovery discs.

Comment: You can [make a recovery disk in Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive). Or [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533) gives alternatives: Boot Repair (scroll down in [the accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/143482)), [bootsect.exe](http://askubuntu.com/a/137337), [EasyBCD](http://askubuntu.com/a/110679) (but that [may not apply](http://askubuntu.com/a/334288/22949)), [recovery console](http://askubuntu.com/a/110726/22949) ([Shift+F8](http://superuser.com/a/483414/105707)), [LILO](http://askubuntu.com/a/422023/22949). Do any of those help?

Comment: As I didn't do a recovery disc when I got the laptop I am in deep mud.... :) Have done a post on my blog to my friends to tell them about it.  All previous windows computer came with recovery discs.

Comment: I do need a recovery disc as I don't have Windows 8.1 on here at all now... so have to reinstall from fresh.